# System.Windows.Forms.Timer is not accurate

Tags: c#, timer

I am using Timer Tick event to execute methods every one second. I see that these methods are consuming time in miliseconds, so I have tried the following code but it is still not executing in the exact one second every tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        Method1();
        Method2();
        Method3();

        sw.Stop();

        TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}", ts.Milliseconds);
        timer1.Interval = 1000 - ts.Milliseconds;
        label1.Text = timer1.Interval.ToString();
        label2.Text = elapsedTime;
    }
```

Comment: The forms timer is not meant to be "accurate". Windows is not an RTOS, how accurate do you need it?

Comment: @RonBeyer I want exactly run every one second.. Because my application needs to record real time and export it to csv, so if the tick is exactly one second the csv file will show correct time, not repeated time or missing one second for example

Comment: Not possible on a Windows system, sorry. Best you can hope for is probably within 15ms using timers (not the forms timer, it's much slower) If you run a thread in a loop you may be faster, but don't do that in a Windows Forms application unless you use a dedicated thread. But even then you can't get it exact because of the way Windows does process scheduling.

Comment: Timer is only guaranteed not to be fast. - You can try some of the other timers..

Comment: How accurate are you look to get?  Windows is a multi-process operating system and there are process that may have higher priority which may give some small differences than what you are looking for.  Giving your application higher priority will give better results but never be exactly every 1msec, but the average should be very close.

Comment: @jdweng is it posibble to make higher priority for winforms timer?

Comment: Process priority should not be changed and won't make any difference anyway. The issue is that you are using a GUI timer which doesn't have the levels of precision you hope for. You need a different solution to your problem.

Comment: I disagree with you again David!!!  Higher priority processes will have less standard deviation.  The timer accuracy is 100nsec, but the it is the latency that is the issue.  Really the average time should be used and not individual samples which will eliminate the need to change priority.